# Quadtree implementation in C++ : Exception Thrown Read Access Violation

Tags: c++, sfml, quadtree

I am attempting to implement a quadtree in C++, however I have a read access violation that I have been spending hours trying to figure out. Note that I have put all the member variables in public, just for debugging efforts.

Whenever I attempt to subdivide a quadrant, ie the root quadrant, I get

Exception thrown: read access violation.
std::_Vector_alloc > >::_Myend(...) returned 0xDDDDDDE9.

The quadtree consists of a pointer to an array of contiguous Quadrants, as well as points. These pointers are passed onto every quadrant, so they are able to write to it without making copies.

What am I doing wrong + could you suggest improvements?

Here is my Quadtree Class:

```
  class Quadtree
{
private:

    Boundary rootBoundary;
public:
    std::vector<Ball>* dataPtr = nullptr;
    std::vector<Quadrant>* quadrantPtr = nullptr;
    Quadtree(const Boundary& b);


};

    Quadtree::Quadtree(const Boundary& bo)
    :rootBoundary(bo)
{
    std::vector<Ball>* bPtr = new std::vector<Ball>;
    std::vector<Quadrant>* qPtr = new std::vector<Quadrant>;
    quadrantPtr = qPtr;
    dataPtr = bPtr;


    Quadrant Root(bo, quadrantPtr, dataPtr);

}
```

The quadtree houses all of the quadrants, as well as the data storage.

Here is the Quadrant class:

```
 class Quadrant
    {
    private:

    public:
        std::vector<Quadrant>* quadrantPtr = nullptr;
        std::vector<Ball>* dataPtr = nullptr;
        Boundary m_boundary;
        std::vector<unsigned int> elementIndex;
        int first_child_index = -1;
        int count = 0;

        Quadrant(Boundary b, std::vector<Quadrant>* qPtr, std::vector<Ball>* dPtr);
        void Subdivide();
        bool Insert(Ball* Ball);
        void Display(sf::RenderWindow& myWindow);

    };


Quadrant::Quadrant(Boundary b, std::vector<Quadrant>* qPtr, std::vector<Ball>* bPtr)
    :dataPtr(bPtr), quadrantPtr(qPtr), m_boundary(b)
{
    qPtr->push_back(*this);
}
void Quadrant::Subdivide()
{
    float cx = m_boundary.m_Centre.x;
    float cy = m_boundary.m_Centre.y;
    float qw = m_boundary.m_halfSize.x / 2;
    float qh = m_boundary.m_halfSize.y / 2;

    sf::Vector2f halfSize{ qw, qh };
    first_child_index = quadrantPtr->size();

    Boundary NE(sf::Vector2f{ cx + qw, cy - qh }, halfSize);
    Quadrant NEQ(NE, quadrantPtr, dataPtr);
    Boundary NW(sf::Vector2f{ cx - qw, cy - qh }, halfSize);
    Quadrant NWQ(NW, quadrantPtr, dataPtr);
    Boundary SE(sf::Vector2f{ cx + qw, cy + qh }, halfSize);
    Quadrant SEQ(SE, quadrantPtr, dataPtr);
    Boundary SW(sf::Vector2f{ cx - qw, cy + qh }, halfSize);
    Quadrant SWQ(SW, quadrantPtr, dataPtr);


}

bool Quadrant::Insert(Ball* ball)
{
    if (!m_boundary.ContainsPoint(*ball))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (count < 4)
    {
        elementIndex.push_back(dataPtr->size());
        count++;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (first_child_index == -1)
        {
            std::cout << "subdividing" << std::endl;
            Subdivide();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (quadrantPtr->at(first_child_index + i).Insert(ball))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

}

void Quadrant::Display(sf::RenderWindow& myWindow)
{
    myWindow.draw(m_boundary.boundary);
    if (first_child_index != -1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            quadrantPtr->at(first_child_index + i).Display(myWindow);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the boundary class which represents the AABB for the quadrant:

```
class Boundary
{
private:

public:
    sf::Vector2f m_Centre;
    sf::Vector2f m_halfSize;
    sf::RectangleShape boundary;
    Boundary();
    Boundary(const sf::Vector2f& centre, const sf::Vector2f& halfSize);
    bool ContainsPoint(const Ball& ball) const;
    ~Boundary();

};

Boundary::Boundary()
{

}
Boundary::Boundary(const sf::Vector2f& Centre, const sf::Vector2f& HalfSize)
    :m_Centre(Centre), m_halfSize(HalfSize)
{
    boundary.setSize(m_halfSize + m_halfSize);
    boundary.setOrigin(m_halfSize);
    boundary.setPosition(m_Centre);
    boundary.setFillColor(sf::Color::Transparent);
    boundary.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::White);
    boundary.setOutlineThickness(2);
}
bool Boundary::ContainsPoint(const Ball& ball) const
{
    bool contains = false;
    if (ball.ball.position.x > m_Centre.x - m_halfSize.x && ball.ball.position.x < m_Centre.x + m_halfSize.x)
    {
        if (ball.ball.position.y > m_Centre.y - m_halfSize.y && ball.ball.position.y < m_Centre.y + m_halfSize.y)
        {
            contains = true;
        }
    }
    return contains;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a comment to show the line at which line the error appears?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  Where is the `main` function that uses your classes?  Also, why are these pointers: `std::vector<Ball>* dataPtr = nullptr;  std::vector<Quadrant>* quadrantPtr = nullptr;`?  Why not simply `std::vector<Ball>` and `std::vector<Quadrant>`?

Answer (score -1):

Your `Root` is local to the constructor. That is, it is destroyed right at the end of `Quadtree` construction. Make it a class member instead.

Also you don’t need to create vectors with `new`, they are basically pointers themselves. Make them class members too, and use `&` to take address to pass into `Quadrant` (or pass a reference).

N.B. Member order is important, it is the order in which they are initialized.

Comment: But `push_back(*this)` makes a copy of the `Quadrant` before it is destroyed.  So it isn't a problem, that `Root` gets destroyed, right?  I mean, they all get destroyed.  Just look at `Quadrant::Subdivide()`.  Even a `Quadrant` makes a copy of its `Boundary` object.  Perhaps the problem is that they weren't intended to be copies at all?  This answer lacks a description of the actual problem.

Comment: Whoops, missed that you make a copy of a partially-constructed object and not taking a reference. But that's UB IIRC.

Comment: And I don't see how do you call these functions. `Quadrant::Insert` requires great care, for example.

Comment: Indeed assigning `*this` in the constructor can't work in a well defined way if the derived class constructor hasn't executed yet.  Likely won't produce a black hole or anything weird until you define a class that inherits from `Quadrant`.